# Can't allocate more RAM to Java Server

Tags: memory, java

I am running a Minecraft .jar server and i want to allocate more RAM to it. Whenever i use the script`"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" -server -d64 -Xms2G -Xmx5G -jar server.jar -o true nogui
pause` the server should start with 2G and use up to 5G. Instead, it tops at 1G and stays there.

How can i make it use more than 1G ?

The computer I use has Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64 and 8G of RAM